# total value is not changing after calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fCuXE/5/).

In the fiddle there is a number of mark textboxes. Type a number in the text box and keep clicking on the add question button. You will see that the total marks remaining equals `10` but it doesn't change. The number of marks remaining should change by subtracting each number in the appended row.

For example, if total marks remaining is `10` and you append four rows, each row containing marks of `1`, then total marks remaining should be `6`. (`10 - 4 = 6`.) But why is it not changing the number of marks remaining?

This is the function where it performs the calculation:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
   var totalweight = totalmarks;
   $("#qandatbl td.weight input").each(function (i, elm){
        totalweight = totalweight - Number($(elm).val(), 10);
    });

    $("#total-weight").text(totalweight);
}
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML

Comment: Are you sure it should'nt be `parseInt` and not `Number`, and you can always use `-=` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your jsfiddle you dont have inputs inside table#quandatbl.
Try change function to

```
function calculateTotal()
{
   var totalweight = totalmarks;
   $("#qandatbl_onthefly_container td.weight input").each(function (i, elm){
        totalweight = totalweight - Number($(elm).val(), 10);
    });

    $("#total-weight").text(totalweight);
}
```

Comment: I forgot I changed the table to include that id and thus need to change some of the ids in the jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question, it seems you want to fetch the values from `table#qandatbl_onthefly` not `table#qandatbl`.

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var totalweight = totalmarks;
    $("#qandatbl_onthefly td.weight input").each(function(i, elm) {
        totalweight = totalweight - Number($(elm).val(), 10);
    });
    $("#total-weight").text(totalweight);
}
```